# google map api on type without selection form submition

Tags: javascript, forms, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

While working with google map api everything is working. But it allow user to type in the box on bases options list will appear below. But without selection user is allowed to submit the form on typed keywords. How do I make user restrict to select an option and submit if he not select any option then error shows him to select an address.

```
var autocomplete_mobile;
var autocomplete;
window.onload = function initialize_gm(){
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */
    (document.getElementById('autocomplete')), {
        type: ['address'],
        componentRestrictions: {
            country: "us"
        },
        strictBounds: true
    }
    /* {type: ['establishment'],componentRestrictions: {country: "us"}} */
    );
    var autocompleteLsr = google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {});
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        var startPos;
        var geoOptions = {
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
            timeout: 30000
        }
        var geoSuccess = function(position) {
            google.maps.event.removeListener(autocompleteLsr);
            google.maps.event.clearInstanceListeners(autocomplete);
            jQuery(".pac-container").remove();
            startPos = position;
            var latitude = startPos.coords.latitude;
            var longitude = startPos.coords.longitude;
            var center = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                center: center,
                radius: 50000
            });
            autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
                /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */
                (document.getElementById('autocomplete')), {
                    type: ['address']
                });
            autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
        };
        var geoError = function(error) {
        if (error.code == 1) {
            //  bootbox.alert('You\'ve decided not to share your position.');
            } else if (error.code == 2) {
                //bootbox.alert('The network is down or the positioning service can\'t be reached.');
            } else if (error.code == 3) {
                //bootbox.alert('The attempt timed out.');
            } else {
                //bootbox.alert('Location detection failed.');
            }
        };
     }
}
```